# Autohotkey - Ctrl combination randomly deletes text as I type

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My **m** key is broken, so I am using an autohotkey script to restore its functionality.

**m** is set as **Ctrl** + **,**

```
^,:: send m
```

Every once and a while, pressing this combination deletes everything that I am typing. Am I accidentally activating a command in Windows?

Comment: Does this happen only in certain applications?  Ctrl+ is used for zooming in most browsers

Comment: @BrianAdkins To clarify, the combo is [ctrl and ,] not [ctrl +]

Comment: This happens regardless of the application being used.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the $ symbol to your hotkey?

```
$^,:: send m
```

See http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols for an overview and background info.

or make sure the ctrl is UP?

```
$^,:: send {ctrl up}m
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *remap* your keys using a third party software so they will be properly defined.

Using AutoHotkey for what you are trying to accomplish is not the correct tool.

The Third Software writes in the BIOS while AutoHotkey replaces the signal.

AutoHotkey uses some of your CPU for your operations.

Help Page from AutoHotkey for reference :

Remapping via the Registry's "Scancode Map"
Advantages:

Registry remapping is generally more pure and effective than AutoHotkey's remapping. For example, it works in a broader variety of games, it has no known alt-tab issues, and it is capable of firing AutoHotkey's hook hotkeys (whereas AutoHotkey's remapping requires a workaround).
If you choose to make the registry entries manually (explained below), absolutely no external software is needed to remap your keyboard. Even if you use KeyTweak to make the registry entries for you, KeyTweak does not need to stay running all the time (unlike AutoHotkey).
Disadvantages:

Registry remapping is relatively permanent: a reboot is required to undo the changes or put new ones into effect.
Its effect is global: it cannot create remappings specific to a particular user, application, or locale.
It cannot send keystrokes that are modified by Shift, Control, Alt, or AltGr. For example, it cannot remap a lowercase character to an uppercase one.
It is not supported on Windows 95/98/Me (AutoHotkey can do some limited Win9x remapping).
It supports only the keyboard (AutoHotkey has mouse remapping and some limited joystick remapping).
How to Apply Changes to the Registry: There are at least two methods to remap keys via the registry:

Use a program like KeyTweak (freeware) to visually remap your keys. It will change the registry for you.
Remap keys manually by creating a .reg file (plain text) and loading it into the registry. This is demonstrated at www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-56216.html#56216

Here is the section describing your problem :

Registry remapping is generally more pure and effective than AutoHotkey's remapping. For example, it works in a broader variety of games, it has no *known alt-tab issues*, and it is *capable of firing AutoHotkey's hook hotkeys* (whereas AutoHotkey's remapping requires a workaround).

Check the AutoHotkey Help Page if your run into another problems !